# Javascript Timer function continue in another page without a restart

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, timer

I have a simple countdown timer  which counts down from 15 seconds downward.
Now, when the **next** button is clicked, i want the timer to continue(not restart) on the new page from the time it left off  in the previous page.
I'm using code igniter php.

```
    //timer.js
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 15,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});


  $('.choice').on('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
action="<?php echo base_url('Gameplay'); ?>
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Gameply",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {question: current_question},
    success: function(res){
        alert(url)
    }
})
```

});

Template:

```
  <div class = "form-group" id="">
                <h3><span class="label label-warning time" id="time" ><?php
                        echo $question; echo $counter

                        ?></span></h3>

        <form method="post" class="choice" action="" id="radioform">
                  <?php
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        echo "<div class=\"radio\"><label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" id=\"checkbox1\" value=\"$option\" >$option</label></div>";
                    }?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger-outline pull-right btn-sm">
                </form>

                </div>
```

//php

```
public function gameplay()
    {
        $question_session = $this->session->userdata();
        $questions = $question_session['question_details'];
        if (!empty($questions)) {
            $current_question = $question_session['question_details'][array_rand(($question_session['question_details']))];
             $current_question_key = array_search($current_question, $question_session['question_details']);
            unset($question_session['question_details'][$current_question_key]);
            array_values($question_session['question_details']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('question_details', $question_session['question_details']);
            $current_question['counter'] = $current_question_key + 1;
            json_encode($current_question);
            $this->load->view('gameplay', $current_question);
```

The issue is now that i keep getting a **current_question is not defined** error in the console.
Also, is there anyway i can check if ajax is actually loading the url i specified?

Comment: How about saving a timestamp in your sessions. And continue with that timestamp if its available.

Comment: Pass the current time, into a hidden field using the `onsubmit` event. If the current time is set, start it at that, otherwise start at the default time.

Comment: Probably it would be better to store the timer value in a cookie instead of passing to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 browser storage:

if you want to set it from controller you can use:

Put everything in script tag.

To set:

```
 localStorage.setItem('last_time', '10');
```

To get:

```
 localStorage.getItem('last_time');
```

To Remove:

```
localStorage.removeItem("last_time");
```

This way you can continue the timer to next page.